# Why does the author of <Learning Python>(5th editon) ask such a question in the quiz?

Tags: python

The reason why I ask such a question here is because I think it maybe relate to  the program culture of Python.

On page 441， why does the author of `<Learning Python>(5th editon)` ask such a question(No. 5) in the quiz? I'm not a native English speaker, so it's a hard thing for me to understand the purpose of the author here.

> **Test Your Knowledge: Quiz**
>   1. How are for loops and iterable objects related?
>   2. How are for loops and list comprehensions related?
>   3. Name four iteration contexts in the Python language.
>   4. What is the best way to read line by line from a text file today?
>   5. **What sort of weapons would you expect to see employed by the Spanish Inquisition?**

Comment: It is a joke. There is a widespread joke about the famous Monty Python quote "Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition". Python's name was inspired by Monty Python, and indeed, it is an unexpected question, so that is why it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, three years later, I figure it out myself!

From Oxford Dictionary

> ( often humorous ) used to say that you do not like the fact that sb
>   is questioning you a lot about sth
>   e.g. `What is this? The Spanish Inquisition?`

---

[The Spanish Inquisition from wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spanish_Inquisition)
" The Spanish Inquisition " is a series of sketches in Monty Python's Flying Circus, Series 2 Episode 2, first broadcast 22 September 1970, parodying the real-life Spanish Inquisition. This episode is itself entitled "The Spanish Inquisition". The sketches are notable for their principal catchphrase, "Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!", which has become a frequently-used quote.
......

This is a recurring sketch always predicated on an unrelated sketch in which one character mentions that they "didn't expect a Spanish Inquisition!", often in irritation at being questioned by another.
......

After entering, **Ximénez begins listing their `weapons` ("fear, surprise, ruthless efficiency"),** but interrupts himself as he keeps forgetting to mention additional weapons and has to begin his list over again.[3][5] After several attempts, Ximénez states that he will come in again, and herds the Inquisition back off the set. The straight man mill worker repeats the cue line, the Inquisition bursts back in (complete with jarring chord), and the introduction is tried anew. But Ximénez fails again and tries to get Cardinal Biggles to do the introduction, but Biggles is also unsuccessful.

---

On page 21， the author of 《Learning Python 5th editon》 mentions about `The Spanish Inquisition in Monty Python`?

> It’s Named After Monty Python
>
> OK, this isn’t quite a technical
>   strength, but it does seem to be a surprisingly well-kept secret in
>   the Python world that I wish to expose up front. Despite all the
>   reptiles on Python books and icons, the truth is that Python is named
>   after the British comedy group Monty Python—makers of the 1970s BBC
>   comedy series Monty Python’s Flying Circus and a handful of later
>   full-length films, including Monty Python and the Holy Grail, that are
>   still widely popular today. Python’s original creator was a fan of
>   Monty Python, as are many software developers (indeed, there seems to
>   be a sort of symmetry between the two fields...). This legacy
>   inevitably adds a humorous quality to Python code examples. For
>   instance, the traditional “foo” and “bar” for generic variable names
>   become “spam” and “eggs” in the Python world. The occasional “Brian,”
>   “ni,” and “shrubbery” likewise owe their appearances to this namesake.
>   It even impacts the Python community at large: some events at Python
>   conferences are regularly billed as **“The Spanish Inquisition.”**
>
> All of this is, of course, very funny if you are familiar with the shows, but
>   less so otherwise. You don’t need to be familiar with Monty Python’s
>   work to make sense of examples that borrow references from it,
>   including many you will see in this book, but at least you now know
>   their root. (Hey—I’ve warned you.)

SO

`What sort of weapons would you expect to see employed by the Spanish Inquisition?` maybe
a banter of the author with readers that what additinal kind of difficult questions do the readers need after they are tortured by unwillingly answering questions in the quiz from the author himself

Comment: The answer to the question posed in the book is: Amongst the Spanish inquisition’s weaponry are such diverse elements as fear, surprise, ruthless efficiency, an almost fanatical devotion to the Pope, and nice red uniforms. You can see the whole bit here: https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xsefeg (Skip to ~30s if you hate fun.)